How to create a "Select All" feature in a checkbox group?
I'm using Shiny for Python and I've been trying to include a checkbox in the checkbox group that will select all / deselect all the items in the group. I've tried a lot of different codes and can't figure it out.
The below code produce checkbox "Select All" but it's above the checkbox group "Regions" and not inside the rest of the checkbox groups, and checking the box does not select/deselect items in the group.
df = dataframe #has column "R_O" that contains 6 different regions in RO_list below as values.

RO_list = ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "Denver", "Los Angeles", "New York", "Philadelphia"]

app_ui = ui.page_sidebar(
    ui.sidebar(
        ui.input_checkbox("select_all", "Select All", value=False),
        ui.input_checkbox_group(
            "R_O",
            "R O",
            RO_list,
            selected=RO_list,
            inline=True, 
        ),

     ui.layout_columns(
        ui.card(
            ui.card_header("R O"), 
            ui.output_data_frame("RO__table"), 
            full_screen=True
        ),
    ),

def server(input, output, session):
    @reactive.Calc
    def r_o_options():
        return ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "Denver", "Los Angeles", "New York", "Philadelphia"]

    @reactive.Calc
    def r_o_selected():
        # If "Select All" is checked, select all options; otherwise, use the user's selections
        if input.select_all:
            return r_o_options()
        else:
            return input.R_O or []
    
    @reactive.Calc
    def exit_data():
        # Filter the data based on the selected regions
        df2 = df[df["R_O"].isin(r_o_selected)]
        return df2
    
    @render.data_frame #data table with counts of regions
    def RO__table():
        RO_table = exit_data()['R_O'].value_counts(dropna=False) 
        RO_table_df = pd.DataFrame({'Regional Office':RO_table.index, 'Count':RO_table.values})
        return render.DataGrid(RO_table_df) 

app = App(app_ui, server)


Edit your question and provide a minimal, reproducible example. Your code is missing the needed modules, several brackets in the ui, the definition of df and so on.

edits made for reproducible example. This is as minimal as possible to produce the result.

No. 1) Modules missing, 2) df = dataframe but dataframe undefined, 3) too many commas in the ui (not closed) and so on.

Here's a simple demo in shinyexpress:
from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import input, ui

ui.input_checkbox_group(
    "checkbox",
    "checkbox",
    ["A", "B", "C", "Select all"],
    selected = "A",
    inline = True, 
)

@reactive.effect
@reactive.event(input.checkbox)
def select_all():
    if "Select all" in input.checkbox():
        ui.update_checkbox_group("checkbox", selected=["A", "B", "C", "Select all"])


This works only partially. "Select All" checkbox is created and selecting the box will select all options. However, when I click one of the options-option A for example- to deselect it, instead of "Select All" button being deselected and option A deselected, option A becomes deselected for a split second but becomes selected again. I think it's because ""Select All" button is still selected. Also, deselecting the selected "Select All" does not deselect all options.

How should I edit it so that the "Select All" checkbox works just like Tableau or excel filter where checking it would select all options, but once you click another option, "Select All" would be deselected. Also, deselecting the selected "Select All" will deselect all options?

I figured out how to do it in case anyone is interested!
RO_list = ["A", "B", "C"]

app_ui = ui.page_sidebar(

### Add sidebar
ui.sidebar(
    ##RO filter
    ui.input_checkbox_group(
        "Regional_Office",
        "Regional Office",
        RO_list,
        selected=RO_list,
        inline=True,
    ),
    ui.input_checkbox("RO_select_all", "Select All", value=True),
)



@reactive.Effect
def update_Regional_Office():
    if input.RO_select_all() == 0: #if select all is not selected,
        ui.update_checkbox_group("Regional_Office", selected= []) #clears RO checkbox group
    elif input.RO_select_all() % 2 == 0: #if even number of select all is selected,
        ui.update_checkbox_group("Regional_Office", choices=RO_list) #shows all options without any changes in selection
    else: #if odd number of select all is selected (only 1 checkbox = selected = odd number)
        ui.update_checkbox_group("Regional_Office", choices=RO_list, selected= RO_list) #all options on RO checkbox group is selected

